# How to run a Java Class in Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I have done a lot of research and, I could not find how to solve my problem. I saw that there are a lot of people who ask this question, but still none of them answered it for me.

I am a beginner at java and I made a simple calculator in Eclipse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double fnum, snum;
        String operation;

        System.out.println("First number: ");
        fnum = numInput.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Second number: ");
        snum = numInput.nextDouble();

        Scanner oper = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please select one of the following operations: ");
        System.out.println("+");
        System.out.println("-");
        System.out.println("/");
        System.out.println("*");

        operation = oper.next();

        switch (operation){

            case "+":
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (fnum + snum));
                break;

            case "-":
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (fnum - snum));
                break;

            case "*":
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (fnum * snum));
                break;

            case "/":
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (fnum / snum));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Later I went into the Workspace folder to find the Calculator.class file.

I opened terminal and typed:

```
Danylo-RIB:~ mac$ java /Users/mac/Documents/workspace/Calculator/bin/Calculator.class
```

I followed all the instructions on how to run a class in MacOs Terminal, but all I got for an answer in my terminal instead of my program was:

```
Danylo-RIB:~ mac$ java /Users/mac/Documents/workspace/Calculator/bin/Calculator.class 
Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.mac.Documents.workspace.Calculator.bin.Calculator.class
Danylo-RIB:~ mac$
```

So my question is, how do I do this? How do I run a class in Terminal?

EDIT: Okay, thanks to the people who answered my question!

Comment: Why not just run from Eclipse?

Comment: When compiling you write the _file name_ to compile.  When running you set up your classpath and then write the _class name_ to run.  This is hard for all new Java programmers.

Answer (score 4):

cd into the directory in which your `Calculator.java` file is stored, run

```
javac Calculator.java
```

this will create a file `Calculator.class`. You can now run the compiled class with

```
java Calculator
```

mind that there is no `.class` to be added!

Answer (score 2):

The online docs should be your first recourse: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html
which tell us that the command line is

```
java [options] classname [args]
```

In more depth, and linked from somewhere on that page, you can read 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB

which is applicable to pretty much all the Java tools. These docs contain the answer to your question. You can either `cd` into the directory that is the root of your classpath and use the default classpath, as one answer suggested, or use the classpath options described in the docs to set the directory(-ies) at the top of your classpath. E.g.,

```
java -cp /Users/mac/Documents/workspace/Calculator/bin Calculator
```

Comment: @Ribchinski The other answers do only work because as a beginner you are *not yet* working with packages, but you will do so later. Thus they are only a temporary solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these simple steps:

```
From Terminal install open jdk

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Write a java program and save the file as filename.java.

Now to compile use this command from the terminal:

```
javac filename.java
```

If everything works well, then a new `filename.class` file should be created.

To run your program that you've just compiled type the command below in terminal:

```
java filename
```

Answer (score 0):

From Command Line:

> `>javac Calculator.java`

It will generate Calculator.class file. 
Then

> `>java Calculator`

Run the program if it finds the main method.

(Java Environment variable should be set and must execute it from the folder where `Calculator.java` is kept.)

If you're using eclipse, then simply hit the Play button from the eclipse tool bar.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to create a runnable .jar file.

First, you need to export jar file for the class. You can do this by right clicking to the `.java` file. Then `Export > Runnable Jar` file as in the picture.

Next step is to run it on the terminal by `java -jar your_runnable_jar_file.jar`.

[image: Exporing jar file]